# F-algebras in 2-categories

Tags: reference-request, category-theory, 2-categories

Given a functor $F : C \to C$, one can usually study the $F$-algebras: morphisms $\alpha : F X \to X$. Where can I read about its generalisation to 2-categories? I think that one can consider now "lax"-homomorphisms between algebras, for example. Where can I read about this?

Comment: Are you maybe looking for *lax algebras* https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/lax+algebra+for+a+2-monad ?